# How to find all PDF files in directories and their subdirectories?

Tags: command-line, ls

I want to list all PDF files in the directories of the current working directory. What command can do this?

I remember a combination of `ls` and `*/*.pdf` but don't remember what exact combination.

Comment: Do you want a list of all pdf files or a list of all files which have the filenameextension ".pdf"?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use:

`find -iname '*.pdf'`

with `ls` maybe:

`ls -lR | grep '/\|pdf$'`

Comment: Firs command does not work, output: ls: cannot access *.pdf: No such file or directory

Comment: ups, sorry. that command is indeed wrong. I'll edit

Comment: Always quote `find` patterns (as in `-name '*.pdf'`), to prevent the shell to expand the glob pattern (this would happen if you have some pdf file in the current directory).

Comment: In case you happen to have files named with inconsistent character case, use `-iname \*.pdf` to also find files ending in .PDF, .PdF, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Use find

```
find . -name '.pdf'
```

See also: http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm

Comment: Shouldn't this be `find . -name '*.pdf'`?

Comment: You do not need a wildcard with find

Comment: You do on Mac @Panther

Comment: @khaverim what OS is Mac?

Comment: On Ubuntu I also need `find . -name '*.pdf'`

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way (if you are using Ubuntu Desktop):

Go to your home folder in Nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for `.pdf`.

[image: Screenshot showing search process]

You can also change the location and you can make your search more specific.

> [**@WarriorIng64**](https://askubuntu.com/users/18612/warrioring64)
>   Note that this on its own will locate all files with .pdf occurring anywhere in the filename. If you specifically want files that the system identifies as PDFs, click the green + button next to "Reload", add the "File Type" "Pdf / Postscript" filter and click "Reload" to get only actual PDFs.
>   [image]

Comment: @WarriorIng64 UPDATED

Comment: Beautiful. Crazy I forgot how simple this was.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command:

```
ls | grep .pdf
```

Comment: how about that! Very simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `ls */*.pdf`

Also, if you wanted to list all PDF files in the current working directory and its subdirectories, you could do `ls *.pdf */*.pdf` :)

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way will be:

```
locate *.pdf
```

This command will find all the PDF files present in your system.

Comment: Watch out for shell globbing doing magic here for you. If the `*.pdf` expands to files in the current working directory, then these will be provided to the `locate` command, not the raw `*.pdf` argument.