# Where can I find the .png or .jpeg of the music, videos, documents, etc. folder icons?

Tags: 11.10, unity, icons, folder

I made a link to the Music folder (for example), and the folder is not the same music folder icon in the home folder, but it's a folder with a black arrow on it. Where can I find the picture files for the icon? It's kind of hard to explain. I am trying to change the icon from the one with the black arrow to the default one in the home folder.

[image: Music folder icon]

[image: The link folder icon]

I want the bottom Music icon to the Music icon on top.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/104831/how-to-delete-all-the-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-a-folder-and-all-of-it/104836#104836 < how to find

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100086/how-to-find-all-pdf-files-in-directories-and-their-subdirectories/100096#100096

Comment: The icon is here: /usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/48

Comment: i thought he's saying that he wants to find in his whole system .png

Answer (score 2):

They will either be installed in `~/.themes` ,`/usr/share/unity/themes/`, or `/usr/share/themes/`. Once you find the location just look for the icons inside the folder. The icons may also be located in `~/.icons`.