# Compress PDF recursively - Find PDF in directories and subdirectories and execute script

Tags: find

I want to execute a script on each PDF in all subdirectories but I have a problem with filenames containing spaces.
I've searched a lot and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100086/how-to-find-all-pdf-files-in-directories-and-their-subdirectories) seems to be a solution but I don't find a way to make my script work.

In a folder, this works great :

```
for f in *.pdf;  do
    filename=$(basename -- "${f}") && extension="${filename##*.}" && filename="${filename%.*}" && outpt="$filename-compressed.pdf"
    echo "$filename"
    echo "$outpt"
    gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE \
    -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$outpt" "${f}";
    # rm "${f}";
done;
```

I then tried to search recusively (before adding "gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ......")

```
for f in $(find "$(pwd)" -name '*.pdf'); do 
    filename=$(basename -- "${f}") && extension="${filename##*.}" && filename="${filename%.*}" && outpt="$filename-compressed.pdf"
    echo "$filename"
    echo "$outpt"
done
```

But I can't get the filenames correctly. May be because of spaces in filenames ?

Thanks for help if you have an idea !

------------------ SOLVED thanks @steeldriver

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -execdir sh -c '
for f do
    filename=${f##*/} && extension=${f##*.} \
        && filename=${filename%.*} && outpt=$filename-compressed.pdf
    gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$outpt" "$filename.pdf"; 
    echo "$filename"
    echo "$outpt"
    # rm "$filename.pdf" # remove original
done' find-sh {} +
```

Comment: Lots of files, filenames with spaces? Read `man find xargs`, and start with `find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty doit`, where `doit` is a `bash` script that you write. Read `man bash`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm discovering '| xargs', avec now see all pdf files appearing correctly. I don't see how to add a bash script to execute `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$outpt" "${f}";` on each file found by 'find' comand. Sorry for small knowledge. I've tried this but outputfile isn't accepted : `find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty bash -c '{ gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="comp-{}" {} ; }' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `for filename in` will spit on characters in the current `IFS` variable - by default, that's space and tab as well as newline.

While you could use find's `-print0` and read the results with a null-delimited `xargs` or null-delimited shell `while` loop, you could just as well use find's `-exec` or `-execdir` to pass filenames unambiguously to a shell command via its positional parameters:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c '
  for f do 
    filename=${f##*/} && extension=${f##*.} \
      && filename=${filename%.*} && outpt=$filename-compressed.pdf
    echo "$filename"
    echo "$outpt"
  done' find-sh {} +
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I now get all filenames correctly but if I add `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$outpt" "$filename.pdf"; ` I get an empty xxx-compresssed.pdf in the folder I launched the script, for each pdf found. Is there a way to get a compressed pdf in the same place the original pdf was found ? Sorry for my lack of knowledge about shell.

Comment: @kobano apologies - I just copied your command. It sounds like you really don't want to remove the leading path component (i.e. should omit the `filename=${f##*/} &&` step). Alternatively you could probably change `-exec` to `-execdir` which will make the path component `./`

Comment: Yes I need `filename=${f##*/} && ...` to specify the output filename. And `-execdir` is exactly what I needed ! I discover it and learn again. Thanks a lot !